# How to intrepret values of the ASP.NET Requests/sec performance counter?

Tags: asp.net, performancecounter, requests-per-second

If I monitor ASP.NET Requests/sec performance counter every N seconds, how should I interpret the values? Is it number of requests processed during sample interval divided by N? or is it current requests/sec regardless the sample interval?

Answer (score 1):

It is dependent upon your **N number of seconds** value. Which coincidentally is also why the performance counter will always read 0 on its first **nextValue()** after being initialized. It makes all of its calculations relatively from the last point at which you called **nextValue()**.

You may also want to beware of calling your counters **nextValue()** function at intervals less than a second as it can tend to produce some very outlandish outlier results. For my uses, calling the function **every 5 seconds** provides a good balance between up to date information, and smooth average.